# Why is a hyperplane a linear transformation kernel of any nonzero linear map from the vector space to the underlying field.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

I am tying to wrap around my head regarding the [wolframalpha](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperplane.html) definition of a hyperplane and I want to understand why it is a linear transformation (always?). Is this a direct deduction from some other properties or..?

Comment: It's a definition. It generalizes a line in a 2d-plane, which is also defined by $a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 = c$.

Comment: So you're saying it had been discovered that a property where linear transformation kernels  without the zero linear map were termed a hyperplane. I was thinking it was deduced from the  codimensional-1 vector subspace property

Comment: Ah, well, it has codimension one -- the only orthogonal vector is the vector of coefficients $(a_1, ..., a_n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $k$, and consider a hyperplane $W$ in $V$. Then any non-zero linear map $f : V/W \to k$ is injective, and then we have $\ker f = \{W\}$. It follows that if $\pi : V \to V/W$ is the canonical projection, then $$\ker(f \circ \pi) = \{v \in V : f(v+W)=0\} = \{v \in V : v+W = W\} = W.$$ Conversely, if $g : V \to k$ is a non-zero linear map, then it is surjective, and then we have $$\dim(\ker g) = \dim V - \dim k = \dim V-1,$$ that is, $\ker g$ is a hyperplane in $V$.

Comment: This makes it more difficult to understand, I’m just starting the topic on bi(linear) forms and quadratic forms can you simplify

Answer (score 0):

If you want it follows from the dimension formula, sinnce the image of a nonzero map of the dual space is 1. So the Kernel must have dimension $n-1$ where $n$ is the dimension of the space. Another way to look at this geometrically is with the Notion of scalar product. A hyperplane is the zero locus of a linear functional, as is the space of all vectors orthogonal to the function seen as a vector. (A linear functional is a raw vector, you transpose that and you obtain the vector orthogonal to the hyperplane)

Comment: Where does the linear transformation kernel come into play

Comment: If you take the span of $n-1$ linearly independent vectors and you want to describe this space as cartesian equations you obtain only one equation describing the space. This equazion is linear ad corrisponds evidently to a zero locus of a linear functional.

Comment: I have a rough idea now, thanks